# sort nested dictionary keys numerically

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

if I have a dictionary like this

```
{'even': {'1': 'odd', '0': 'even'}, 'odd': {'1': 'even', '0': 'odd'}}"
```

I want to sort this dictionary and make it look like this

```
{'even': {'0': 'even', '1': 'odd'}, 'odd': {'0': 'odd', '1': 'even'}}"
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't meant to be an ordered data type, why did you want to do this? What have you done so far to try and do this?

Comment: May be you would like to use `OrderedDict` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since python 3.6/3.7, dictionaries are ordered by insertion order, so it is possible to sort a dict. If you are using an older version of python, then it is not possible: dicts are not ordered.

Here I give a function to sort a dict by keys, and use it with one level of nesting.

```py
d = {'even': {'1': 'odd', '0': 'even'}, 'odd': {'1': 'even', '0': 'odd'}}

def sorted_simple_dict(d):
  return {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items())}

def sorted_once_nested_dict(d):
  return {k: sorted_simple_dict(v) for k, v in sorted(d.items())}

sorted_d = sorted_once_nested_dict(d)
# {'even': {'0': 'even', '1': 'odd'}, 'odd': {'0': 'odd', '1': 'even'}}
```

If you want to sort arbitrarily deep nested dicts, you can use recursion and `isinstance( , dict)`:

```py
d = {'even': {'even': {'even': {'1': 'odd', '0': 'even'}, 'odd': {'1': 'even', '0': 'odd'}}, '1': 'odd', '0': 'even'}, 'odd': {'1': 'even', '0': 'odd'}}

def sorted_nested_dict(d):
  if isinstance(d, dict):
    return {k: sorted_nested_dict(v) for k, v in sorted(d.items())}
  else:
    return d

sorted_d = sorted_nested_dict(d)
# {'even': {'0': 'even', '1': 'odd', 'even': {'even': {'0': 'even', '1': 'odd'}, 'odd': {'0': 'odd', '1': 'even'}}}, 'odd': {'0': 'odd', '1': 'even'}}
```

**See also:**

- [How do I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48155267/3080723)